# pyodbc - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position n: invalid start byte

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, utf-8, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to read a data frame from a sql query but keep getting an error saying 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position n: invalid start byte. Code as below. How to fix this error? Thanks

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SSXBYXSQL107,5269;DATABASE=INV_Q1;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
conn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding = 'utf-8')

sql_query="select [inventory_desc] from [INV_Q1].[INV_Detail].[Inventory]"
df_inv=pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
```

Comment: The error means that your database is not delivering you UTF-8 data. How to fix? Select the encoding of your data, or tell your database client to deliver you the data in the expected encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for now, SQL Server does not send Unicode characters as UTF-8; it sends them as UTF-16LE, and UTF-16 is the default encoding expected by pyodbc. Those `setencoding`/`setdecoding` calls are not applicable for connections to SQL Server.

As mentioned in the [pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#microsoft-sql-server):

> SQL Server's recent drivers match the [ODBC] specification, so no configuration is necessary. Using the pyodbc defaults is recommended.